# Update statement using pyodbc and SQL Server General Network Error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

So I wrote some code to update an SQL server using values from a pandas DataFrame. Upon running the following code, the iteration keeps going until a certain point when it gets stopped by an error.

```
for index in range(len(description)):
   cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=x.database.windows.net; DATABASE=x; uid=x; pwd=x;)
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("UPDATE Product SET MetaDescription = ? WHERE Id = ?", description['Description'][index], description['Id'][index])
   cnxn.commit()
```

It should be noted that I am running a similar code (only the values differ) for another dataframe, containing a string, which runs perfectly and updates the table without errors. This one, however, stops after updating around 300 rows. The first error was this one:

> Error: ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv()). (65534) (SQLEndTran); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')

And after running it again, I got this one:

> Error: ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv()). (65534) (SQLEndTran); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')

The only difference between the DataFrame that is working and the one that just stops is the length of the strings, but the SQL Server dtype is set to nvarchar(max). What could be the problem here?

Comment: Check the values for which it is throwing error's by using `try:..except:..`

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and see if I can get more info about the causes of the error.